# Chess/Graph theory puzzle

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Consider a standard 8 by 8 chess board. Black has 4 pieces; a Queen and 3 pawns, which can be placed anywhere on the board. Each pawn is "connected" to the Queen by a straight line.

White has a single piece, the King, which follows standard chess movement rules and begins at square A1 (the bottom left corner of the board).

In this game, black only places their pieces on the grid and does not move. It is white's goal to reach the win condition in as little moves as possible, which is either capturing any of black's pieces, or by landing on a square which contains the straight lines which connect black's pawns to their Queen.

THE PROBLEM: White cannot see black's pieces, but will know when the win condition is met. Devise a strategy for white to minimise the amount of moves taken to reach the win condition for an arbitrary black-piece layout.

Notes:

- I have set this problem myself so if there are any caveats that are not explicit, please let me know and I shall clarify.
- The connecting lines can overlap; 3 or more pieces could be all in a line.
- If a straight line touches the corner of a square, white does indeed win by landing in any of the 4 squares which share that corner.

Example:

[image: White wins in 3 moves]
[White wins in 3 moves]

Extension: Can the strategy be altered to solve for an n by n, n by m, or arbitrarily shaped topologically connected space?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... this is a condition of the problem, it is always met.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase. I can't image a set up where this condition is not met, could you give an example? As in: I would think that you can always find a straight line connecting any of blacks pawns with the queen, am I mistaken?

Comment: @ViktorGlombik Yes, of course.  To put it another way, white moves until he either lands on one of the pieces or on one of the lines connecting the queen to a pawn.

Comment: Is there no setup where this condition is not met; you can indeed always find a straight line connecting ALL of the black pawns with the Queen. The purpose of the existence of the line is to provide the white King with an additional win condition, which is to land on a square that contains part of a line.

Comment: Looking at it the other way around, white proposes a path, and then black places the pieces so that the path is not a win.  For example if white's path starts out along the diagonal from A1 to A8, black must place all his pieces in one of the two triangles so determined.  We see that white's path  must dissect the board into regions of no more than $3$ squares each.

Comment: You say an arbitrary black-piece layout - does this mean that, for practical purposes, they are randomly distributed?

Comment: Yes, you could treat them as randomly distributed. Alternatively, you could consider every possible layout of black pieces, for which there are around 2.3-2.5 million of them, depending whether you allow black pieces to be on square A1.